# Import multiple packages in Scala REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

In Scala, I frequently have to import multiple packages worth of implicits and other utilities, particularly on the REPL:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.{mutable => mut}
import com.myapp.db._
import com.orm._
val con = connectDb(...)
...
```

I understand there's no way to import multiple packages in Scala (though package object scopes can help a bit), but what about from the REPL? Is there any way to do this from the REPL without lots of copying and pasting? I also tried using :load, but things imported/created there don't get introduced into the REPL's scope either. I noticed that the :power command *does* import things into scope.

**Update**: `:load` actually *does* work.

Comment: What do you mean *"but things imported/created there don't get introduced into the REPL's scope either"* when using `:load`? Seems to work fine for me for imports and objects...

Comment: You're right - I mistakenly tried `mut.<TAB>` and thought the lack of completions meant nothing was being imported.

Comment: `TAB` is a recursive acronym for `TABs Are Broken`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure of a general solution, but in SBT it's possible to configure the project so that the console (REPL) runs some initial commands upon launching. Here's an excerpt from an [example `build.sbt` file](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Quick-Configuration-Examples),

```
// set the initial commands when entering 'console' only
initialCommands in console := "import myproject._"
```

**Edit**: Another reference is the Scalala project. They have a [Scala program](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalala/ScalalaConsole.scala) that launches an embedded REPL and fills in the necessary imports. For usage, see their [quick-start guide](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala/wiki/QuickStart).

Comment: Also note that you can create a script that uses SBT to invoke REPL with a particular configuration. See SBT 0.10's wiki about scripts.

Comment: @Daniel Sweet! Do you know if you can use SBT to launch non-REPL applications?

Comment: You can use it to launch Scala scripts -- there's an example on the very same page I mentioned, the scripts page on xsbt wiki.

Comment: initialCommands doesn't work for me in the way I specified in the question - the lines get executed, but the symbols aren't actually introduced into the REPL scope.  Marked your answer as accepted anyway though, since :load actually *does* work.

Comment: @Yang, the key thing is that you do not start the REPL by typing "scala", instead you type "sbt console" to start the REPL. Then you can import all the packages which are specified in your dependencies of the build.sbt