# How to import several implicit at once?

Tags: scala

I have several implicit context for my application.
like

```
 import scala.collection.JavaConversions._    
  import HadoopConversion._   
etc
```

Right now I have to copy paste all those imports at each file. Is it possible to combine them in one file and make only one import?

Comment: I think there are/were proposals for "exported" imports, but I am not sure what the status is.

Comment: Objects (not packages) can be used in a similar fashion (e.g. as per Scalaz): http://www.scala-lang.org/node/9719

Comment: And an old thread on "export/include": http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/4003/focus=4027

Answer (score 8):

A good technique that some libraries provide by default is bundling up implicits into a trait. This way you can compose sets of implicits by defining a trait that extends other implicit bundling traits. And then you can use it at the top of your scala file with the following.

```
import MyBundleOfImplicits._
```

Or be more selective by mixing it in only where you need it.

```
object Main extends App with MyBundleOfImplicits {
   // ...
}
```

Unfortunately with something like JavaConversions, to use this method you will need to redefine all the implicits you want to use inside a trait.

```
trait JavaConversionsImplicits {
  import java.{lang => jl}
  import java.{util => ju}
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions  
  implicit def asJavaIterable[A](i : Iterable[A]): jl.Iterable[A] = JavaConversions.asJavaIterable(i)
  implicit def asJavaIterator[A](i : Iterator[A]): ju.Iterator[A] = JavaConversions.asJavaIterator(i)
}

trait MyBundleOfImplicits extends JavaConversionsImplicits with OtherImplicits
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala does not have first-class imports. So the answer to your question is no. But there is an exception for the scala REPL. You can put all your imports in a file and then just tell the REPL where it is located. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963654/import-multiple-packages-in-scala-repl).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers/comments are already comprehensive. But if you just want to reduce COPY/PASTEs, all mainstream IDE/text-editors support text templating ('live template' in IntelliJ IDEA, 'template' in Eclipse, 'snippets' in TextMate ...) that will definitely make your life easier.