# How to add imports to REPL from command line?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

How can I make REPL to import packages given in commnad line?

Sample:

```
scala -someMagicHere "import sys.error"
scala> :imports
1) import scala.Predef._          (162 terms, 78 are implicit)
2) import sys.error               (2 terms)

scala> _
```

PS: It is **not** a duplicate. I want automated solution, not manually pasting some code every time I run REPL. Also I don't want to use SBT just for running one command in REPL after its start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import multiple packages in Scala REPL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963654/import-multiple-packages-in-scala-repl)

Comment: @oluies that answer helps only sbt dandies. We're talking hard-core, shell prompt, ivyless classpaths here.

Comment: you missed https://github.com/scalala/Scalala/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalala/ScalalaConsole.scala

Comment: @som-snytt: The question is a dup, though the answers aren't — they should have gone to the original question.

Comment: @Blaisorblade ha. Maybe they'll change the other question to match the accepted answer there.

Comment: @Blaisorblade This question is: "How to make REPL import **automatically after launch (without user interaction)** selected imports **from command line** (without SBT or any non-standard tools, but possibly with standard unix utils)."; other question is: "How to import **manually** (one-time, e.g. by writing/pasting stuff to the running console) **multiple packages to running** REPL.". I fail to see how these questions could be interpreted as duplicate ~ identical.

Comment: In the other *question*, I read: "Is there any way to do this from the REPL without lots of copying and pasting?". I concede the title might be slightly misleading. But the full question is exactly about "How to make REPL import automatically after launch (without user interaction)". The fact that one answer uses SBT (and thus is bad) is irrelevant. It matters that the *question* is the same.

Comment: @Blaisorblade In the other question I see nothing about completely automatic solution (he even mentions `:load` which as far as I know cannot be used directly from command line). There's only the sentence with "lots of copying and pasting" - so if it's not lots, just one ":load MyStuff.scala" it seems as a valid answer. My question is about "importing packages to REPL **from command line**". I don't even see phrase "command line" anywhere in the other question. So expecting that the answer to my (IMO different question) will appear there, when question has been marked as solved, is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a script to automatize the *command line param to file* thing (based on A from [som-snytt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510229/1017211)). It's tested on win 7 with [MSYS](http://mingw.org/), but it should work on Linux as well.

```
bash-3.1$ repl "import sys.error"
Loading C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp.GgEjauEqwz...
import sys.error

Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.7.0_07).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
scala> :impo
 1) import scala.Predef._ (162 terms, 78 are implicit)
 2) import sys.error (2 terms)
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function crash {
    echo "Error: $1"
    exit 10
}

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Script requires one parameter."
    exit 1
fi

t=$(mktemp) || crash "Unable to create a temp file."
[ ${#t} -lt 1 ] && crash "Suspiciously short file name, aborting."
trap "rm -f -- '$t'" EXIT

echo "$1" > "$t"
scala -i "$t" || crash "Something wrong with scala binary."

rm -f -- "$t"
trap - EXIT
exit
```

Comment: I don't understand the SO workflow, it looks like you proposed sticking this on my answer, and some guys said no you can't do that?  Anyway, I see you wanted to supply the imports. I was thinking more in terms of, reflection-imports.script contains the burdensome import reflect.runtime etc, and an alias for scala -i makes it convenient. I guess I could see a use case for your idea, where you supply a package and it imports everything it can from it. concurrent._, duration._ is another annoyance. BTW, you know it's time to upgrade your scala and java?

Comment: @som-snytt Yes, I wanted to just edit your answer and accept it, but my edit was rejected :(. I'm using it for the exact reason you wrote - importing all stuff with underscore. (I somehow broke the java autoupgrading thingy and it looks I missed a lot of updates, I'll do it manually then.) Thank you for your assistance :).

Comment: How about using all the args, `for arg in $* ; do echo "$arg" >> $f ; done` or similar.

Comment: @som-snytt It's an option. But it already supports multiple commands and it's even shorter: `repl "import a.b.c; import d.e.f"` vs. `repl "import a.b.c" "import d.e.f"`.

Answer (score 5):

Stick it in a file.

```
apm@mara:~/tmp$ scala -i imports.script
Loading imports.script...
import sys.error

Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :impo
 1) import scala.Predef._          (162 terms, 78 are implicit)
 2) import sys.error               (2 terms)
```

Edit:

I think you get bonus points for finding or otherwise provoking or inducing a bug:

```
apm@mara:~/tmp$ scala -e "import sys.error"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```