# How can I have some code loaded in sbt console?

Tags: scala, sbt, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

I'd like to have some code loaded/interpreted upon running `sbt console`. The same code would be shared between projects.

Think of it as something which makes sense in an interactive session only (eg. timing functions) - like `.irbrc` for Ruby, PYTHONSTARTUP script for Python ..etc.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6963731/589273) help?

Comment: Partly.. still I need to find working solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, following the answer from Sacha Kolberg's comment, I adapted something like this:
https://github.com/herenowcoder/rcfiles/blob/8965c73/build.sbt

Still, it requires the chunk of code to be copied to every SBT project.
Anyone having an elegant solution of setting this for all projects (per Unix user)..?

I played with `.sbtrc` as well with no luck.

*[edit]*

By the way, what is cool about loading commands this way, is that console prints type signatures of eval'ed stuff:

`[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
time: [R](block: => R)R
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).`

Still, I'm looking for a way to include such code for every project.
Something in style of Elixir's `.iex.exs` machinery.

*[edit]*

Found it!

Instead of adding an `initialCommands in console := "..."` section to every project involved, it's sufficient to put it in `~/.sbt/0.13/build.sbt`, or - probably more correct - `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt` (both work).

Thanks Sascha Kolberg for putting me on the right track!